# JSP input min: how to +1 to a variable?

Tags: html, mysql, jsp, input, min

so I am currently working on a page where it displays items from my database and allows users to 'bid' on the item. The item has a price and I can currently make the minimum bid price set = the current price on the database as follow:

Browse.jsp

```
<form action="bidItems.jsp">
.
.
.
   <tr> 
      <td colspan="100">
            <input type="number" name="newPrice" value="" min="${ITEMS.newPrice}"/>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Place Bid!">
        </td>
    </tr>
.
.
.
</form>
```

so my question is, if I want to make the minimum of the input to be  (${ITEMS.newPrice} +1), how should I do it? I can't seem to find any related stuff on the web and I tried min="${ITEMS.newPrice} + 1" and it didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this..

```
<input type="number" name="newPrice" value="" min="${ITEMS.newPrice + 1}"/>
```

why *${ITEMS.newPrice} + 1* fails is, when the brasses are closed it consider +1 as HTML text, HTML does not support calculations.. it just display what we feed.

Comment: one more question, say if I want it to submit ${ITEMS.newPrice + 1} as the value when even the number input was left untouched, what should I do?

Comment: do it with JS or make this as the value like value=" ${ITEMS.newPrice + 1}".